# How to switch user from remote shell

Tags: ansible

I am not able to switch user from remote shell.
Also how can I pass password to remote shell.

I tried with play book, command and shell tasks.
But it's not working

This is my code

```
- hosts: test1
  tasks:
    - name: Switch user
      shell: $(echo "{{ su - username }}")
      shell: $(echo "{{ 'password' }}”)
```

Comment: Please show a code sample of what you were doing including the error message

Comment: - hosts: test1
  tasks:
  - name: Switch user
    shell:  $(echo "{{ su - username }}")
    shell:  $(echo "{{ 'password' }}”)

Answer (score 0):

You did a couple of things here that ansible doesn't like. I'm in a good mood so I will break it down for you, in reality this is covered in the  **[excellent documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/intro.html)**

- A task can only have one action
- Each task runs independently of the task before it

Translating what you did to valid ansible syntax the following will happen:

1. The syntax you used tries to expand what is inside of `{{ ... }}` -- that will fail
2. Run a shell with the ssh user that calls `bash -c $(echo "{{ su - username }}")`

```yaml
    - name: Run a single action for each Task
      hosts: test1
      tasks:
        - name: Task 1 # fails with 'standard in must be a tty'
          shell: su - nobody
        - name: Task 2 # never executed because 'Task 1' fails
          shell: whoami
          register: whoami_result
        - name: Task 3 # never executed because 'Task 1' fails
          debug:
            msg: "Result: {{ whoami_result }}"
```

Now for a fixed ansible-playbook:

```yaml
    ---
    - name: Run a single action for each Task
      hosts: test1
      tasks:
        - name: Task 1
          sudo: true # use sudo to change roles
          sudo_user: nobody # the target user under which to execute
          shell: whoami
          register: whoami_result
        - name: Task 2
          debug:
            msg: "Result: {{ whoami_result.stdout }}"
```

```bash
    $ ansible-playbook -u root test1.yml

    PLAY [Run a single action for each Task] **************************************

    GATHERING FACTS ***************************************************************
    ok: [test1]

    TASK: [Task 1] ****************************************************************
    changed: [test1]

    TASK: [Task 2] ****************************************************************
    ok: [test1] => {
        "msg": "Result: nobody"
    }

    PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************
    test1                      : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Comment: No need to specify sudo password?

Comment: You need to make the correct call to ansible-playbook. `ansible-playbook --help` will show you the command line switch to use

Comment: "excellent documentation"? Not my experience so far. Comprehensively opaque, maybe.